# Spatial Left Join on Days and Hours gives wrong value in R

Tags: r, join, left-join, geospatial, shapefile

I have two shape files which I want to left join. Both shape files have Days and Hours columns and in both shape files they are of **class character**. I want to left join both shape files by Days and Hours with following query

```
joined_data <- sf::st_join(shp1,shp2, by = c("Day", "Hour"), left = TRUE)
```

Below is the head of shape1, shape2 and merged file. The merged file is not merging basis on hours and days. I am not sure why but you can check in the last screen shot that  **Day.x, Hour.x** of shape1 file are not matching with **Day.y,Hour.y** of shape2 file. Please click on the pictures for better view. Thanks
[image: Shp 1]
Shape2 File Below
[image: Shp 2]
Merged File of Shape1 and Shape2
[image]

Comment: Usman, how many questions have you asked in the R tag? You have been told to not post screenshots of your data before, it shouldn't have to be more than once. Please use dput

Comment: `st_join` dos not  care about attribute columns, it uses predicate functions (e.g. st_intersects ) to join by geometries.

Comment: @margusl , Sorry I don't get it. What would be the alternative if st_join does not care about columns.

Comment: `dplyr::left_join()`, `base::merge()`. Though you must probably convert one of your sf-objects to data.frame ot tibble first.

Comment: Spatial joins are for spatial joins.

Comment: @dufei do you think if it's any problem in spatial left join ?

Comment: Well, have a look at margusl's comments – a spatial join identifies matching rows via the geometry column but that's not what you are doing. For ordinary joins that do not involve the geometry just use `dplyr::left_join()` or `base::merge()`.